# What is the smallest NFA you can design for {a^n : n =/= 1003}

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, nondeterminism

What is the smallest NFA that could be design for a^n where n!=1003?

I have been racking my brain at this for a while but still can't reduce the number of states required from 1004. Here state(1003) will be a rejecting state and all the other previous state will be accepting state. A transition from state(1003) to state(1004) will result in being in a Final state with a self loop on any concurrent a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i \in \{0, \dots, 1003\}$ let $p_i = (a^i, a^{1003-i})$.

We can then invoke Theorem $1$ in  [1] choosing $P = \{p_0, \dots, p_{1003}\}$ to conclude that a lower bound on the number of states of any NFA is $1004$.

It is easy to come up with a NFA that accepts the language using $1004$ states. Each state is labelled with an integer $i \in \{0, \dots 1003\}$ and, for each $i < 1003$, there is a transition from $i$ to $i+1$ labeled "$a$".

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068873/how-do-we-know-that-an-nfa-has-a-minimum-amount-of-states).

[1] Ian Glaister, Jeffrey Shallit. *A lower bound technique for the size of nondeterministic finite automata*, Information Processing Letters, Volume 59, Issue 2, 1996, Pages 75-77, ISSN 0020-0190, doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(96)00095-6. Also accessible from the [website of one of the authors](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eshallit/Papers/nfa.pdf).

Comment: The DOI link leads to a paywall, but the paper is also available on the page of the author: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/nfa.pdf

Comment: @Stef thank you, I replaced the link in the answer!

Comment: I'm not sure that's actually better. The DOI is meant to be very durable, whereas the personal page of the author at uwaterloo.ca can easily become unavailable, especially if the author changes university in the future. Even though I couldn't read the paper at Elsevier, the doi at least gave me the name of the paper and the list of authors, so it was easy to search for it.

Comment: If you're feeling zealous you could add the full reference at the bottom of your answer. *Ian Glaister, Jeffrey Shallit,
A lower bound technique for the size of nondeterministic finite automata,
Information Processing Letters,
Volume 59, Issue 2,
1996,
Pages 75-77,
ISSN 0020-0190,
https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(96)00095-6.*

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a litteral application of the theorem would prove that the complement of the language requires $1004$ states (because $x_iw_i\notin L$ and $x_iw_j \in L$ if $i\neq j$). Could you add an argument why that is not a problem? (computing the complement of a NFA is not always as easy as for DFA's). Also in your set $P$, shouldn't the first element be $p_0$ instead of $p_1$?

Comment: @Nathaniel, you are absolutely right Once cannot just invoke the Theorem as I did. I tried deleting the answer but I cannot since it is accepted.